# How to map a JSON file from an API on React, selecting values to be added on a selector on product details

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, css-selectors

I'm trying to add a couple of selectors on a product details page from a JSON file and I was able to do it properly from an array , the problem is that I am not able to do it from an array of objects. I'll try to show it as clear a possible:

- For product size - (extracted from Json api) - `"size":["30","32"]`
  and from product details page, it works -

  <FilterSize onChange={(e) => setSize(e.target.value)}>
  {product.size?.map((s) => (
  {s}
  ))}
- However I'm not able to get the values using the same structure with an array of objects. Although I guess it shouldn't be so difficult , I've been already hours))
- Colors - (extracted from Json api) - `"colors":[{"code":500,"name":"blue"},{"code":600,"name":"red}]`

  <FilterColor onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}>
  {product.color?.map((s) => (
  {s}

How to alter the formula to get the values under the key "name"?

Comment: Please note https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3001761

Answer (score 0):

Without implementation details of what is filtercolor and what you want from it, it's quite dificult to answer your question.

```
<FilterColor onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
  {product.color?.map((s) => ({s.name}) }
</FilterColor>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Arthur, <FilterColor> is just from Styled Components Css.

Comment: To be more clear I want to get as options on the product selector the values after the key "name" . From the first example there was no problem as it was from a plain array